# External API post request from NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

New to nextjs. Looking for a way to post to an external API link. looked through the documentation, found no tangible examples.
So I have an external register user endpoint.
I need to post to that endpoint with the user input.
the page looks like this

```
class signup extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
        }
    }

    signup = e => {
        let body = {
            firstName: firstname,
            lastName: lastname,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            username : email,
            password: password
        }
        //Call to Register API
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.signup}>Register</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    //What to do here?
}

export default signup;
```

Now how do I set up the getServerSideProps() function so that it works on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` is server side function that fetches data that your page needs to display. It has nothing to do with client side requests.

If you want to send client side request after user interaction (click), you can use `window.fetch` method, for example, or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), if you want to simplify things. Like you usually do in regular React app, it is not specific to Next.js in any way.

```
import axios from 'axios';

// ...


    signup = e => {
        let body = {
            firstName: firstname,
            lastName: lastname,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            username : email,
            password: password
        }
        //Call to Register API

        axios.post(INSERT_API_URL_HERE, body).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Another query if I may. Will redux be a good choice for nextjs or the server-side functions does the job?

Comment: Depends on your application. If you have lots of shared state then sure, you would need some sort of state manager like Redux.